# How to change bitmap in live wallpaper from preference activity in android

Tags: android, bitmap, live-wallpaper

I have made an live wallpaper. I want to change the bitmap of the wallpaper from the preference activity. I am initializing the bitmap within the constructors and calling`canvas.drawbitmap()` into my main thread.

The bitmaps has been initializes once in the constructor. I want to change the bitmap in the preview screen too in the wallpaper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give value to bitmap in a separate method and call it in your constructor. call it from **onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible)** for a change if it is visible before your draw method.